# Showing equivalence of complex equalities

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me with the following question:

> Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ be three different complex numbers. Show that the equalities $$|z_1-z_2|^2=|z_2-z_3|^2+|z_3-z_1|^2$$ and $$z_2-z_3=i\lambda(z_3-z_1), \quad \lambda\in\mathbb R $$ are equivalent and give geometric interpretation of this fact.

My attempt to answer this question was to firstly use the identity $|z|^2=z\overline z$:

$\displaystyle \text{LHS}= (z_1-z_2)\overline{(z_1-z_2)}=(z_1-z_2)(\overline{z_1}-\overline{z_2})=|z_1|^2-2 \text{Re}(z_1\overline{z_2})+|z_2|^2\\
\text{RHS}=|z_2|^2-2\text{Re}(z_2\overline{z_3})+2|z_3|^2-2\text{Re}(z_3\overline{z_1})+|z_1|^2$

Equating:

$-2\text{Re}(z_1\overline{z_2})=-2\text{Re}(z_2\overline{z_3})+2|z_3|^2-2\text{Re}(z_3\overline{z_1})$

I didn't see that going anywhere, so I tried to assume that $\text{Re}(z_1-z_2)=|z_2-z_3|$ and that $\text{Im}(z_1-z_2)=|z_3-z_1|$ (it could be the other way round or not true), but that idea didn't seem to be going anywhere.

I thought that I should look at $\displaystyle\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_3-z_1}$ to see why it is an imaginary constant.

I also thought that it might be useful to set $z_1-z_2=p,\quad z_2-z_3=-(q+p)\ $ and $\ z_3-z_1=q$. Then I get $p^2=|q+p|^2+q^2$ and $|i\lambda q|^2=p^2-q^2$.

Comment: I need to go offline for 3 hours.

Comment: You have surely recognized Pythagoras in the first equation. The second equation expresses that there is a right angle at $z_3$, that's all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a triangle with verteces $z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$. Then $|z_1-z_2|$ is the length of the edge determined by $z_1$ and $z_2$ and so on for the others. Hence your hypothesis implies (by Pythagore) that $z_1,z_2,z_3$ is a right triangle at $z_3$. Thus, if you apply a rotation of $\pi/2$ to one edge (in the good direction), followed by a rescaling, you will get the other edge. But applying a rotation of $\pi/2$ is precisely performing a multiplication by $i$ and the multiplication by $\lambda$ is the rescaling. Here $\lambda$ can be negative if the rotation has to be done clockwise.

This is a pure geometrical argument, but if you draw a picture, it should be clear.